# Combine awk and another command to send report to user

Tags: bash, shell

I need small help related to Unix shell script using awk.
I have a file like below:

```
139341  8.61248 python_dev  ntoma2  r   07/17/2017 07:27:43 gpuml@acepd1641.udp.finco.com   1
139342  8.61248 python_val  ntoma2  r   07/17/2017 07:27:48 gpuml@acepd1611.udp.finco.com   1
139652  8.61248 python_dev  ntoma2  r   07/17/2017 10:55:57 gpuml@acepd1671.udp.finco.com   1
```

Which is space separated. I need to get 1st col and 4th col which are job-id and user-name(ntoma2 in this case) based on 6th col (which is date in date formate - mm/dd/yyyy), older than 7days. Compare 6th column with current date and I need to get cols which are older than 7days.

I have below one to get Job id and user name of older than 7 days:

```
cat filename.txt | awk -v dt="$(date "--date=$(date) -7 day" +%m/%d/%Y)" -F" " '/qw/{ if($6<dt) print $4,":",$1 }' >> ./longRunningJob.$$
```

Also i have another command to get email ids like below using user-name (from the above 4th col):

```
/ccore/pbis/bin/enum-members "adsusers" | grep ^UNIX -B3  | grep <User-Name> -B2 | grep UPN | awk '{print $2}'
```

I need  to combined above 2 commands and need to send a report to every user as like below:

```
echo "Hello <User Name>, There is a long running job which is of job-id: <job-id> more than 7days, so please kill the job or let us know if we can help. Thank you!" | mailx -s "Long Running Job"
```

NOTE: if user name repeated, all the list should go in one email.

I am not sure how can i combine these 2 and send email to user, can some one please help me?

Thank you in advance!!
Vasu

Comment: @Vasu now you need to delete the first comment to avoid confusion of what is wrong and what is right....

Comment: We'd need to see some output from `/ccore/pbis/bin/enum-members "adsusers"` to determine how to map username to email address.

Comment: User object [001] (XXXXXXXX)\n
============\n
Enabled: \n
Distinguished name: \n
SAM account name: \n
NetBIOS domain name: \n
UPN: email@FINCO.COM\n
Display Name:\n
Alias: user-name\n
UNIX name: \n
GECOS:\n
Shell: \n
Home directory: \n
Windows home directory: \n
Local windows home directory:\n
UID: \n
Primary group SID: \n
Primary GID: \n
Password expired: \n
Password never expires: \n
Change password on next logon:\n
User can change password:\n
Account disabled:\n
Account expired:\n
Account locked:\n

Comment: This is only one user's record, out put contains bulk of above text blocks. In one block, i am interested in UPN (Which is email id) and Alias (Which is user name), I am sorry for bad formatting. NOTE: In above block \n indicates next line.

Comment: Thank you for checking this for me Glenn!! Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution, but there is a bug in it, here is the solution:

```
!#/bin/bash

{ qstat -u \*; /ccore/pbis/bin/enum-members "adsusers"; } | awk -v dt=$(date "--date=$(date) -7 day" +%m/%d/%Y) '
 /^User obj/     {
                  F2 = 1
                  FS = ":"
                  T1 = T2 = ""
                  next
                 }
 !F2             {
                  if (NR < 3) next
                  if ($5 ~ "qw" && $6 < dt) JID[$4] = $1 "," JID[$4]
                  next
                 }

 /^UPN/          {T1 = $2
                 }
 /^Display/      {T2 = $2
                 }
 /^Alias/        {gsub (/ /, _, $2)
                  EM[$2] = T1
                  DN[$2] = T2
                 }
 END             {for (j in JID) {print "echo -e \"Hello " DN[j] " \\n \\nJob(s) with job id(s): " JID[j] " executing more than last 7 days, hence request you to take action, else job(s) will be killed in another 1 day \\n \\n Thank you.\" | mailx -s \"Long running job for user: " DN[j] " (" j ") and Job ID(s): " JID[j] "\" " EM[j]
                                 }
                 }
 ' | sh
```

The bug in the above code is -- the if condition of date compare (as shown below) is is not working as expected, i am really not sure how to compare the $6  and the variable dt (both of format mm/dd/yyyy). I think i should use either mkdate() or something else. can some one please help?

```
if ($5 ~ "qw" && $6 < dt)
```

Thank you!! 
Vasu

Comment: I believe i dont need to use another awk variable (dt in this case), there should be some other way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this in awk -- easier in gawk because of date support.

Just to give you an outline of how to do this, I wrote this in Ruby:

```
$ cat file
139341  8.61248 python_dev  ntoma2  r   07/10/2017 07:27:43 gpuml@acepd1641.udp.finco.com   1
139342  8.61248 python_val  ntoma2  r   07/09/2017 07:27:48 gpuml@acepd1611.udp.finco.com   1
139652  8.61248 python_dev  ntoma2  r   07/17/2017 10:55:57 gpuml@acepd1671.udp.finco.com   1

$ ruby -lane 'BEGIN{ require "date"
                  jobs=Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }
                  users=Hash.new()
                  pn=7.0
            } 
            t=DateTime.parse("%s %s" % [$F[5].split("/").rotate(-1).join("-"), $F[6]])
            ti_days=(DateTime.now-t).to_f
            ts="%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds" % [60,60,24]
                    .reduce([ti_days*86400]) { |m,o| m.unshift(m.shift.divmod(o)).flatten }
            users[$F[3]]=$F[7]
            jobs[$F[3]] << "Job: %s has been running %s" % [$F[0], ts] if (DateTime.now-t).to_f > pn
            END{
                jobs.map { |id, v| 
                   w1,w2=["is a","job"] 
                   w1,w2=["are","jobs"] if v.length>1
                   s="Hello #{id}, There #{w1} long running #{w2} running more than the policy of #{pn.to_i} days. Please kill the #{w2} or let us know if we can help. Thank you!\n\t" << v.join("\n\t")
                   puts "#{users[id]} \n#{s}"
                   # s is the formated email address and body. You take it from here...

                }
            }

' /tmp/file
gpuml@acepd1671.udp.finco.com 
Hello ntoma2, There are long running jobs running more than the policy of 7 days. Please kill the jobs or let us know if we can help. Thank you!
    Job: 139341 has been running 11 days, 9 hours, 28 minutes and 44 seconds
    Job: 139342 has been running 12 days, 9 hours, 28 minutes and 39 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you So much for your time and this Solution dawg, unfortunately I have to wrote this in shell script with awk because of some limitations that i have. So if you could help me using awk(i am assumming that you have enough knowledge on shell scripting using awk), it will be great, Thank you!!